# Python Selenium - can't find elements by xpath for div and a tags using class name as attribute

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am currently scraping TripAdvisor and am running into issues locating elements by xpath for `div` and `a` tags when using the class name as an attribute.
The url i am currently working with is: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g30620-Huntsville_Alabama-Hotels.html

For example, this line of code should click the right arrow at the bottom of the page to go to the next page:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='xkSty']/div[@class='UCacc']/a")))
```

but it does not work and returns a TimeoutException every time. I have verified this xpath is valid on the actual TripAdvisor page using the console. This happens for all `div` and `a` tags if I use a class attribute. However, when I try to locate elements such as buttons or tables using the class name as an attribute, it works. For example:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='rmyCe _G B- z _S c Wc wSSLS pexOo sOtnj']"))).click()
```

works and expands the number of hotels on the page.

I am unsure how to proceed because I can't understand why it can't locate the element. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement scrolling to get that button into viewport. Only then it is possible to interact with the element.

Selenium has the wheel implementation to achieve that. It can scroll to the desired element. See:

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/wheel/

It is also possible to use javascript for scrolling. Though it will not scroll the element into view.

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```